# Funcionalidade JAVA em comparação com Delphi para localizar um valor em lista específica

Tags: java, delphi

Olá, alguém saberia me dizer se existe uma funcionalidade no JAVA semelhante ao Locate do Delphi?

```
If Lista.Locate('REGIAO;PRODUTO',
                VarArrayOf([REGIAO.AsString,
                PRODUTO.AsString]),[]) Then[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o List tem várias funções, seria bom dar uma olhadinha rápida nelas. Não sei qual a finalidade que estás procurando, mas lá vai um exemplo.

```java
List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>(); //inicia uma lista de produtos
produtos.add(new Produto(123,"shampoo"));
produtos.add(new Produto(456,"condicionador"));
produtos.add(new Produto(789,"creme"));

Produto sabonete = new Produto (147,"sabonete");
if(produtos.contains(sabonete)){ //verifica se a lista contém o objeto
   //o produto sabonete está contino na lista
}

int index = produtos.indexOf(sabonete); //retorna o indice da primeira ocorrencia do objeto, caso não exista na lista retorna -1;
```